# How do I disable the Market App Fast Web Install feature in my android phone settings?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-play-store, htc-desire-hd, settings

I do not quite like the [Fast Web Install](http://scitechie.com/02/how-to-install-applications-from-the-android-market-web/) idea of [Market](https://market.android.com/) app.

I use [AppBrain](http://AppBrain.com) for my app installs and it lets me manually select if-and-when I would like to install or update an app selected from my AppBrain account to my phone.

That is (I noticed) not the case with the Market app. So, if I (or someone gaining access to my google account) were to select an install from Market, it would just get installed on my phone shortly -- no questions asked.

Similarly, I prefer to install apps when the phone has a Pass-Through or WiFi data connection. But, this auto-triggered install can happen any time -- I don't like that either.

I could not find any settings in my Market app that will make it ask before it downloads and installs an app. I would like to control this at the phone (rather than from my Market account login).

Answer (score 2):

The Fast Web Install feature relies on Background Data being enabled.  If you turn this off, (Settings > Account & Sync > Background Data) any apps you select in the Market website will not be downloaded to your phone.

When you switch Background Data back on, anything you (or your nefarious account accessor) have queued will be downloaded.

Comment: That will work, but not for me. I don't won't to stop my data connection just because Market app does not let me turn off a web-based install.

Comment: Fair enough. I think you may be out of luck in that case. Bear in mind though that killing Background Data doesn't kill your whole data connection, just (some of the) things that happen behind your back.

Comment: I know. But, I really don't want to impact any other data activity from my android in the interest of disabling a remotely triggered install. I strongly feel that this should be an option in the phone-end of the mechanism (the market app on my android).

Answer (score -2):

In the preference for the AppBrain application there are settings to enable and disable Fast Web Install.

Menu > Preferences > Disable Fast Web Install.

Comment: I have seen AppBrain controls and have in-fact used them as a reference example for my Market App expectations. Using AppBrain app does not stop my Market App from being active and used. I would like to disable the Market App completely (but, without any root operations) and continue to use AppBrain if that is possible.